# Bash bind command

Tags: bash

I have a very curious situation, when logged n terminal to my Centos host the capital r does not work, it doesn't type anything.

It does work when i'm editing files for example.

After long search of possible issue I think I found the problem is that I have no bind association for the `R`, see and extract from the output of `bind -p`:

```
=======

"M": self-insert
"N": self-insert
"O": self-insert
"P": self-insert
"Q": self-insert
"S": self-insert
"T": self-insert
"U": self-insert
"V": self-insert

============
```

as you can see the "R" is missing, how do I add it? please keep in mind I cannot type "R" in my terminal :)

Comment: Maybe a prank by a friend?

Comment: Check `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile`, `/etc/bash_completion`, `/etc/bash_completion.d/*` for the `bind R:...` command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
bind '"R":self-insert'
```

or this, if you can't type "R":

```
bind '"'`echo -e '\x52'`'":self-insert'
```

Comment: the second command did it, have to make it permanent, will try add to some startup file

Answer (score 1):

```
rcap=$(echo r | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]')
```

This command sets `rcap` variable to `R`. Now you can use `$rcap` instead of `R` anywhere, e.g. in a command that restores the binding of `R`:

```
bind "$rcap":"self-insert"
```

Of course you can also edit a script and source it from `bash`, and there you can use `R`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the mapping is removed somewhere. Run `bash -x` to start a new shell and see which commands are executed while it starts.

You can also try to add `bind "R":"self-insert"` to your `.bashrc` and start a new terminal.