# Bash / Linux : "s" character ignored in prompt

Tags: linux, bash, centos7

**OS** : CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

**Bash Version** : GNU bash, version 4.2.46(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

I'm running into a very strange issue.

On this server, I can't use my "s" key anymore. Typing the "s" key just prints nothing on the prompt. However, I see that the server gets a input by the way the blinking "_" reacts (don't know how to call this thing..)

Furthermore, I'm not able to copy / paste the "s" character from another display. For example, copying / pasting the string "sysconfig" will result in pasting only "yconfig".

The only way I found to have a "s" character on the prompt is via the autocompletion. For example, by taping "/etc/ba" + TAB, this will display /etc/bashrc. I'm then able to use the "s" character in other commands.
I can alos use the history to use this character (using the "s" of a previous typed command)

On the login prompt, I am able to use the "s" character.
I'm also able to use this character in a text editor as vim.

I made no recent changes to my bash_profile (which I actually didn't changed at all since the server installation), nor to other major system parameters, as far as I can remember. The only concern might be the loaded keys as I'm using the French keys (loadkeys fr).

I tried the following :

- Testing my keyboard : I'm able to use the "s" character elsewhere
- Rebooting the server : Same problem happens
- Loading the US keys : Same problem happens

I must say I'm clueless on this issue, so I call for your help !

Thanks in advance.

M.

By the way, this is my first question on this website. Please tell me if you see a way I could have improved my question.

---

**Edit following @chepner first workaround** (see more details in the comment)

**Workaround** has been found by @chepner : `bind $'"\x73": \x73elf-in\x73ert'` rebound the `s` character to the `s` key.

However, this is not persistent after a reboot. It appears there is something that is binding the `s` key to do something else. To further inverstigate the root cause of the issue, I provide here the output of the command `bash -x` :

```
[root@localhost ~]# echo $INPUTRC

[root@localhost ~]# bash -x
+ alias 'rm=rm -i'
+ alias 'cp=cp -i'
+ alias 'mv=mv -i'
+ '[' -f /etc/bashrc ']'
+ . /etc/bashrc
++ '[' '\s-\v\$ ' ']'
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ case $TERM in
++ '[' -e /etc/sysconfig/bash-prompt-xterm ']'
++ '[' 0 -ge 3405 ']'
++ PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007" "${USER}" "${HOSTNAME%%.*}" "${PWD/#$HOME/~}"'
++ shopt -s histappend
++ history -a
++ shopt -s checkwinsize
++ '[' '\s-\v\$ ' = '\s-\v\$ ' ']'
++ PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '
++ shopt -q login_shell
++ '[' 0 -gt 199 ']'
++ umask 022
++ SHELL=/bin/bash
++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/256term.sh ']'
++ '[' '[\u@\h \W]\$ ' ']'
++ . /etc/profile.d/256term.sh
+++ local256=
+++ '[' -n '' ']'
+++ '[' -n '' ']'
+++ unset local256
++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/colorgrep.sh ']'
++ '[' '[\u@\h \W]\$ ' ']'
++ . /etc/profile.d/colorgrep.sh
+++ /usr/libexec/grepconf.sh -c
+++ alias 'grep=grep --color=auto'
+++ alias 'egrep=egrep --color=auto'
+++ alias 'fgrep=fgrep --color=auto'
++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/colorls.sh ']'
++ '[' '[\u@\h \W]\$ ' ']'
++ . /etc/profile.d/colorls.sh
+++ '[' -z '[\u@\h \W]\$ ' ']'
+++ '[' -z '' ']'
+++ alias 'll=ls -l'
+++ alias 'l.=ls -d .*'
+++ INCLUDE=
+++ COLORS=
+++ for colors in '"$HOME/.dir_colors.$TERM"' '"$HOME/.dircolors.$TERM"' '"$HOME/.dir_colors"' '"$HOME/.dircolors"'
+++ '[' -e /root/.dir_colors.xterm ']'
+++ for colors in '"$HOME/.dir_colors.$TERM"' '"$HOME/.dircolors.$TERM"' '"$HOME/.dir_colors"' '"$HOME/.dircolors"'
+++ '[' -e /root/.dircolors.xterm ']'
+++ for colors in '"$HOME/.dir_colors.$TERM"' '"$HOME/.dircolors.$TERM"' '"$HOME/.dir_colors"' '"$HOME/.dircolors"'
+++ '[' -e /root/.dir_colors ']'
+++ for colors in '"$HOME/.dir_colors.$TERM"' '"$HOME/.dircolors.$TERM"' '"$HOME/.dir_colors"' '"$HOME/.dircolors"'
+++ '[' -e /root/.dircolors ']'
+++ '[' -z '' ']'
+++ '[' -e /etc/DIR_COLORS.xterm ']'
+++ '[' -z '' ']'
+++ '[' -e /etc/DIR_COLORS.256color ']'
++++ /usr/bin/tty -s
++++ /usr/bin/tput colors
+++ '[' x8 = x256 ']'
+++ '[' -z '' ']'
+++ '[' -e /etc/DIR_COLORS ']'
+++ COLORS=/etc/DIR_COLORS
+++ '[' -n /etc/DIR_COLORS ']'
+++ '[' -e '' ']'
++++ /usr/bin/dircolors --sh /etc/DIR_COLORS
+++ eval 'LS_COLORS='\''rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:'\'';
export LS_COLORS'
++++ LS_COLORS='rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:'
++++ export LS_COLORS
+++ '[' -z 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=01;05;37;41:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=01;36:*.au=01;36:*.flac=01;36:*.mid=01;36:*.midi=01;36:*.mka=01;36:*.mp3=01;36:*.mpc=01;36:*.ogg=01;36:*.ra=01;36:*.wav=01;36:*.axa=01;36:*.oga=01;36:*.spx=01;36:*.xspf=01;36:' ']'
+++ /usr/bin/grep -qi '^COLOR.*none' /etc/DIR_COLORS
+++ unset TMP COLORS INCLUDE
+++ alias 'll=ls -l --color=auto'
+++ alias 'l.=ls -d .* --color=auto'
+++ alias 'ls=ls --color=auto'
++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/lang.sh ']'
++ '[' '[\u@\h \W]\$ ' ']'
++ . /etc/profile.d/lang.sh
+++ sourced=0
+++ '[' -n en_US.UTF-8 ']'
+++ saved_lang=en_US.UTF-8
+++ '[' -f /root/.i18n ']'
+++ LANG=en_US.UTF-8
+++ unset saved_lang
+++ '[' 0 = 1 ']'
+++ unset sourced
+++ unset langfile
++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/less.sh ']'
++ '[' '[\u@\h \W]\$ ' ']'
++ . /etc/profile.d/less.sh
+++ '[' -x /usr/bin/lesspipe.sh ']'
+++ export 'LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s'
+++ LESSOPEN='||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s'
++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/vim.sh ']'
++ '[' '[\u@\h \W]\$ ' ']'
++ . /etc/profile.d/vim.sh
+++ '[' -n '4.2.46(1)-release' -o -n '' -o -n '' ']'
+++ '[' -x /usr/bin/id ']'
++++ /usr/bin/id -u
+++ ID=0
+++ '[' -n 0 -a 0 -le 200 ']'
+++ return
++ for i in '/etc/profile.d/*.sh'
++ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/which2.sh ']'
++ '[' '[\u@\h \W]\$ ' ']'
++ . /etc/profile.d/which2.sh
+++ alias 'which=alias | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde'
++ unset i
++ unset -f pathmunge
++ printf '\033]0;%s@%s:%s\007' root localhost '~'
[root@localhost ~]#
```

I'm not able to understand everything that's happening here. I had a look at several of some of the files that are called, but found nothing relevant. I might miss something though, as I'm not used to read this output and don't know how to interpret all of this.

Can you please tell me if you see what is bindind the `s` key to something else as the `s` character ?

Thanks.

M.

Comment: Check the output of `bind -p | grep $'"\x73":'`; the output should be `"s": self-insert`. If it isn't, something rebound your `s` key to do something else. Note this would be consistent with what you are observing, that only programs that use the Readline library are affected.

Comment: »*The blinking "_"*« is called *cursor* :D   Very interesting problem btw.

Comment: @chepner : The output of `bind -p | grep $'"\x73":'` is empty. Thanks for your comment. Do you know how to bind it back ?
@Socowi : Yeah, the cursor, right :D

Comment: OK, at least as a quick fix, you should be able to run `bind $'"\x73": \x73elf-in\x73ert'` as necessary to restore the functioning of your `s` key. For a longer term fix, you'll have to figure out what deleted the binding for `s` in the first place. Look in `~/.inputrc` or any `bash` configuration files you use.

Comment: Thanks @chepner, that did the trick. I'm able to use my `s` key again. This is not persistent and the issue comes back after a reboot. Having a look at my bach configuration file, I see I edited the `~/.inputrc` back in April to add `set-bell-style none` and there is nothing else in this file. The other files in my homdir are : `.bash_history`, `.bash_logout`, `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, `cshrc`, `.tcshrc` and `.viminfo`. I never touched those files. If you have an idea .. Thanks anywy for your help so far, very useful

Comment: I think `~/.inputrc` is the only standard file that `Readline` uses, but check to see if the variable `INPUTRC` is set to instruct `bash` to load a different file. Otherwise, try running `bash -x` to see if it is executing any other `bind` commands from some other file.

Comment: @chepner This is very good info!! It would be better to make an answer, not just for the points, but info to be here for future reference.

Comment: @chepner the output of `echo $INPUTRC` is an empty string. Trying to `export INPUTRC=/root/.inputrc` and then `bash` : The new batch is still missing the `s` key binding. I ran `bash -x`and had a look at the output. There don't seem to be an issue from what I see, but I might misunderstand something, as I'm not used to read this output. I updated my question to recap what you found so for, and add the full output of `bash -x`. Could you or someone have a look and tell me if I missed something ? Thank you

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see anything in the output of `bash -x` that would account for `s` being bound to something other than `self-insert`. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you again @chepner for your help so far. Your workaround is really helpful and I will be using it if I need to reboot the server again. If anyone has a clue on how to investigate what's happening .. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting some general information as an answer for futur reference.

If you encounter the same kind of issue and need to rebind a key, you may want to know what hexadecimal code you need to use (`\x73` for the `s` key in my case). Have a look at the [ASCII CODE TABLE](http://www.ascii-code.net/). Don't forget you need to pick the hexadecimal column !

Alternatively, you may run the following command to get the hexadecimal code to character association :

```
for i in `seq 33 126`; do printf '\\x%x => ' $i; echo -e "$(printf '\\x%x ' $i)"; done
```

Other references :

- [Bash bind command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22014683/bash-bind-command)
- http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/bash-simplifying-an-array-4175471861/

Hope that helps.

M.